# CSS: allign horizontally two elements of a list

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a box containing a picture on the top and two buttons at the bottom. The two buttons have to stay inline and centered (at least horizontally).

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="box1">
    <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
</div>
<div id="popinfo2">
    <div>
        <img src="http://imageenvision.com/450/18963-sweaty-woman-skipping-or-dancing-during-cardio-exercise-at-the-gym-clipart-by-djart.jpg">
    </div>            
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">P</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">P</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this the CSS:

```
body{
    background: sandybrown;
    height: 300px;
    width: 90%;
}

#box1{
    position: relative;
    background: mediumseagreen;
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#popinfo2{
    position: relative;
    background: plum;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}

#popinfo2 div{
    position: relative;
    background: lightseagreen;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#popinfo2 div:first-of-type{
    width: 35%;
    height: 75%;
}

#popinfo2 div:nth-of-type(2){
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
}

#popinfo2 div img{
    background: aliceblue;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0; border: 0;
    display : block;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/*#popinfo2 div div{
    background: dodgerblue;
    height: 50%;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0; margin: auto;
}*/

#popinfo2 div ul{
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}


#popinfo2 div ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: auto;
}

#popinfo2 div ul li a {
    float: left;
    padding: 0.5em 3.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background: brown;
    width: 2em;
}
```

The only way I found was to insert a left margin inside the li tag. I don't really like it as it takes the reason of using the percentage off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `display:inline-block` instead of `float` for `<li>` if you want to center horizontaly :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKBeE

float kills display and send things to the extrem right or left of its container , it is not fully in the flow anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c8Txt/)

Firstly, use `inline-block` for the li, then `text-align: center;` will work.
Secondly, check your code wisely - you set `float:left;` to the `<a>` tags inside floated li's.

Comment: a  width + text-align:center on parent doesn't really matter that it is bloc, inline-block or float once it stands in an <li> as inline-block boxe. <li> will hold it